# TEXT() Working on codeblocks but not on visual studio

Tags: c++, findwindow

I have a function that needs to find the window handle by "FindWindow()", which use "LPCSTR" type as parameter, so I have to use "TEXT()" to convert the inputs(I don't really understand why, but I've tested on codeblocks, and it worked)

```
int sendString(char proc_class[], char proc_name[], char str_to_send[])
{
    HWND proc_handle = FindWindow(TEXT(proc_class), TEXT(proc_name));
    ...
```

It worked perfectly on codeblocks(with mingw), but its not working on VS

That's what VS is pointing:

"Expands to: Lproc_class

identifier "Lproc_class" is undefined"

Comment: [C++ string variable in TEXT macro](//stackoverflow.com/a/45208596). Don't use `TEXT` on variables. You probably did not get the error with codeblocks because you were not targeting unicode.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. I will try to convert it in other ways, thanks for answering.

Comment: Suggestion: Try to write the sucker with wide characters end-to-end. It's been 20 years since you really needed to worry about supporting both ansi and wide.

Comment: For future reference `TEXT` is supposed to be only used on string literals.

Comment: And I completely agree with what was said previously. The intent behind `TEXT` and related functions and macros is to be able to write one program which supports both Windows 95/98/Me and Windows NT. As was said earlier that's not been an issue for at least 20 years. Modern Windows uses wide characters, so should you.

Comment: And as a general principle don't try things you don't properly understand. It's hard when you are a newbie because there is a lot you don't understand, but the danger is that you fall into [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: I'll try to learn more about that before really get it working, I learned a lot with you, thank you guys.